# How to Implement Contentful CMS User Resource Access Control?

Tags: authorization, content-management-system, contentful, headless-cms

I'm building a website with different users that belongs to different "accounts"
Is there a way when using Contentful CMS or similar headless CMS service to restrict contents based on user and their accounts?

e.g. This document can only be accessed by users that belongs to account 1234

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about Contentful, but with Content Chef (https://contentchef.io)
you can create different "spaces" and have different users for each space, so you should be able to easily do what you need!

Full disclaimer: I'm working in Content Chef:)

Comment: Hi Davide. I have a question. How do you think your answer will help the OP?

Comment: he's asking if using Contentful CMS or similar headless CMS can somewhat divide contents into different buckets for different users right? I just pointed out that it's a feature available in our product. if this is not relevant I probably misunderstood the question and  I apologize